# How to create Bigtable tables and column families in a Dataflow job if they doesn't exist

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable, apache-beam-io

I have a [Cloud Dataflow job](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/dataflow/example/PubsubWordCount.java) which is writing everything to a single table and a single column family. How to modify this job to write to multiple tables and column families which may or may not exist? E.g., if a table or column family doesn't exist, create one and then write to it.

Comment: Have you checked BigTableIO? What's the behavior of BigTableIO if it reads and writes to something non-existing?

Comment: I did some quick checks, seems like BigTableIO will always assume table exists (or does validation and fail if table not exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/daa32af473f880430c9d4f31bc171157d3b4064a/java/dataproc-wordcount/src/main/java/com/example/bigtable/sample/CreateTable.java) example should show you how to check to see if a table exists, and create it if not.

The `Admin` interface from that code sample can also be used to get the column families for a table (`getTableDescriptor`) and create one if necessary (`addColumn`).